# Spring boot: Pagination from page 1 (one-indexed-parameters) not runs well

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination

my scope is Spring boot 3.1
I'm implemeting REST service and I have pagination for return large list of elements. For default Spring boot manage the page from 0 index.
I have reading that is possible start pagination from page 1, using this senetence in application.yaml:

```
spring:
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        one-indexed-parameters: true
```

With new settings, the page 0 and the page 1 is the same. It show the same result.
The problem is that the param "number" on paginations settings always show one page less, that I access:

Examples:

**To page 0**

```
Request: 
{{base_url}}/system/business/pagination?size=5&page=0

Response details:
    "pagination": {
    "totalPages": 4,
    "totalElements": 17,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "empty": false,
    "first": true,
    "last": false,
    "sorted": false
}
```

*Note: I would prefer that it returns null.*

**To page 1**

```
Request: 
{{base_url}}/system/business/pagination?size=5&page=1

Response details:
    "pagination": {
    "totalPages": 4,
    "totalElements": 17,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "empty": false,
    "first": true,
    "last": false,
    "sorted": false
}
```

*Note: Returns the same that page 0. See that number value is wrong. It would have to be 1.*

**To page 2**

```
Request: 
{{base_url}}/system/business/pagination?size=5&page=2

Response details:
    "pagination": {
    "totalPages": 4,
    "totalElements": 17,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 1,
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "empty": false,
    "first": false,
    "last": false,
    "sorted": false
}
```

*Note: Return the page 2, but number value is 1.*

Any suggestion for fix this wrong operation?
Thanks

Comment: The "number" parameter in the pagination response is still zero-based instead of being one-based as you would expect.

Comment: any workaround on this? and solution?